# create child component with generic formControle

Tags: angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-components

Helo I would like create a child component content form each of my formcontrol from a big formgroup.

Since i can't just pass the formcontrol because he need a formGroup.

The idea and wath i tried is to inject my formgroup in child and pass also a json parameter object for configuration of the child formcontrol (name, type's input, validators'type, ...).

But pass the formGroup each time to the child make my renderer make too much time to render.

But i think it is not the good way practice.

In parent comp

```
 <ctrl
    [config]="'name'"
    [form]="form.get('site')"
    [ctrlName]="'ORDER_FORM_NAME'"
    [ctrlError]="'ORDER_FORM_NAME_ERROR'"
  ></ctrl>
```

the child comp html

```
<form [formGroup]="form">
  <div>
    <label>{{ctrlName}}</label>
    <div>
      <input formControlName="{{config}}" placeholder="{{ctrlName}}">
      <div *ngIf="form.get(config).hasError('required')">
        <span>{{ctrlError}}</span>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</form>
```

I saw on stackoverflow some case to create generic component with injector or viewContainerRef, wath i don't realy want.

If somewone could pass me a link or explain summarily the process, could be very helpfull.

Comment: Finally i followed this tuts https://ultimatecourses.com/blog/angular-dynamic-components-forms

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add `viewProviders` to your `@Component`, and make a service containing your form to inject it in all your child components:

```
@Component({
  selector: '...',
  templateUrl: '...',
  styleUrls: ['...'],
  viewProviders: [{ provide: ControlContainer, useExisting: FormGroupDirective }],
})
```

Comment: Thanks but inject a form in child component with a service could be done without the viewProviders, the are no generic formcontrole there. or my knowledge of viewProviders in not wel understood. what i need is create this formcontrole in a way to not copy past each time my controle.